# How to change CSS elements of an element when hovering on another

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm experimenting with a design. I have a text element that changes colors and glows on hover. It's an `a` element wrapped in a `p`. I have the text in the middle of a circular image. I'd like for the image to change it's border color from transparent to white when `a` is hovered over. I've done some research but can't seem to get any of the solutions to work.

What I've tried,

- `a:hover > img { border-color: #fff; }`
- `a:hover + img { border-color: #fff; }`
- `a:hover img { border-color: #fff; }`
- `a:hover ~ img { border-color: #fff; }`
- Same as above but `p a:hover + img`
- Adding a `class` and `id` to `img`

Please help, here's the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.Hero {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 940px;
  height: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 485px;
  z-index: -999;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  text-shadow: -.75px -.75px 0 #25343f, .75px -.75px 0 #25343f, -.75px .75px 0 #25343f, .75px .75px 0 #25343f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

p a {
  color: #405c71;
  font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
}

p a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 70px #405c71, 0 0 80px #405c71, 0 0 100px #405c71, 0 0 150px #405c71;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #405c71, 0 0 35px #405c71, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 50px #405c71, 0 0 75px #405c71;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- <div class="Hero">
     <video src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/editor.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
  </div> -->

  <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
  <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no CSS selector that does what you are trying to do.

For a:hover + img to work, the image has to be directly after the link. so remove the <p> surrounding the <a>

or wrap both the link and the image inside the paragraph tag like so:

```css
a:hover + img {
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>
<a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a><br/>
<img class="logo" src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/logo.png" alt="">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no ability to *look outside* of the currently specified range of selectors, CSS can only *cascade down*, it cannot *traverse back*.

As it stands now, you could achieve the desired behaviour, using the *adjacent sibling combinator* `+`, with the following selectors: `p:hover + img { border-color: #fff; }`, without any further amendments to the DOM.
Although, this wouldn't be advised as these selectors are *too general* and not *specific enough*, the chances of only having one instance of a `img` tag following a generic `p` tag could be slim and unexpected knock-on effects could occur as a result.

Consider the following adjustments in order to have any one of the below specified range of selectors apply and provide the intended behaviour.

- `a:hover > img { border-color: #fff; }`

**1. Child Combinator `>`:**

- *Type: Combinator*
- *Syntax:* `A > B`
- *See: [Child combinator - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)*

> The `>` combinator selects nodes that are direct children of the first
>   element

*Example:*

HTML

```
<div class="welcome">
  <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
  <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome:hover > img {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```css
/* Additional */

.welcome:hover > img {
  border-color: white;
}

/* End Additional */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.Hero {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 940px;
  height: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 485px;
  z-index: -999;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  text-shadow: -.75px -.75px 0 #25343f, .75px -.75px 0 #25343f, -.75px .75px 0 #25343f, .75px .75px 0 #25343f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

p a {
  color: #405c71;
  font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
}

p a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 70px #405c71, 0 0 80px #405c71, 0 0 100px #405c71, 0 0 150px #405c71;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #405c71, 0 0 35px #405c71, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 50px #405c71, 0 0 75px #405c71;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- <div class="Hero">
     <video src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/editor.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
  </div> -->

  <div class="welcome">
    <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

---

- `a:hover + img { border-color: #fff; }`

**2. Adjacent Sibling Combinator `+`:**

- *Type: Combinator*
- *Syntax:* `A + B`
- *See: [Adjacent sibling combinator - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)*

> The `+` combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the
>   second element directly follows the first, and both share the same
>   parent.

*Example:*

HTML

```
<div class="welcome">
  <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
  <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome p:hover + img {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```css
/* Additional */

.welcome p:hover + img {
  border-color: white;
}

/* End Additional */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.Hero {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 940px;
  height: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 485px;
  z-index: -999;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  text-shadow: -.75px -.75px 0 #25343f, .75px -.75px 0 #25343f, -.75px .75px 0 #25343f, .75px .75px 0 #25343f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

p a {
  color: #405c71;
  font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
}

p a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 70px #405c71, 0 0 80px #405c71, 0 0 100px #405c71, 0 0 150px #405c71;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #405c71, 0 0 35px #405c71, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 50px #405c71, 0 0 75px #405c71;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- <div class="Hero">
     <video src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/editor.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
  </div> -->

  <div class="welcome">
    <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

---

- `a:hover ~ img { border-color: #fff; }`

**3. General Sibling Combinator `~`:**

- *Type: Combinator*
- *Syntax:* `A ~ B`
- *See: [General sibling combinator - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)*

> The `~` combinator selects siblings. This means that the second
>   element follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and
>   both share the same parent.

*Example:*

HTML

```
<div class="welcome">
  <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
  <p>arbitrary element</p>
  <p>another arbitrary element</p>
  <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome p:hover ~ img {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```css
/* Additional */

.welcome p:hover ~ img {
  border-color: white;
}

/* End Additional */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.Hero {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 940px;
  height: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 485px;
  z-index: -999;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  text-shadow: -.75px -.75px 0 #25343f, .75px -.75px 0 #25343f, -.75px .75px 0 #25343f, .75px .75px 0 #25343f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

p a {
  color: #405c71;
  font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
}

p a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 70px #405c71, 0 0 80px #405c71, 0 0 100px #405c71, 0 0 150px #405c71;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #405c71, 0 0 35px #405c71, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 50px #405c71, 0 0 75px #405c71;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- <div class="Hero">
     <video src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/editor.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
  </div> -->

  <div class="welcome">
    <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a></p>
    <p>arbitrary element</p>
    <p>another arbitrary element</p>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

- `a:hover img { border-color: #fff; }`

**4. Descendant Combinator :**

- *Type: Combinator*
- *Syntax:* `A B`
- *See: [Descendant combinator - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)*

> The    combinator selects nodes that are descendants of the first
>   element.

*Example:*

HTML

```
<div class="welcome">
  <p><a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a>
     <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome p:hover img {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```css
/* Additional */

.welcome p:hover img {
  border-color: white;
}

/* End Additional */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.Hero {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 940px;
  height: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 485px;
  z-index: -999;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 415px;
  text-shadow: -.75px -.75px 0 #25343f, .75px -.75px 0 #25343f, -.75px .75px 0 #25343f, .75px .75px 0 #25343f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

p a {
  color: #405c71;
  font-family: Pacifico, cursive;
}

p a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: neon .9s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: neon .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 70px #405c71, 0 0 80px #405c71, 0 0 100px #405c71, 0 0 150px #405c71;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #405c71, 0 0 35px #405c71, 0 0 40px #405c71, 0 0 50px #405c71, 0 0 75px #405c71;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- <div class="Hero">
     <video src="dojo/frontend/photography/images/editor.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
  </div> -->

  <div class="welcome">
    <p>
      <a href="dojo/frontend/photography/index.html">Welcome</a>
      <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/940x940" alt="">
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

*More on [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)*